# Horizontally misalligned sub-/superscripts in fractions when using 'minus' sign

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, subscripts, superscripts

I am combining sub- and superscripts in the denominator of a fraction. I get ill behaviour when the exponent is preceded with a minus sign:
[image]

I would expect the sub- and superscript of the first two elements be aligned. I do understand the different alignment of the third element, when the superscript is absent. However, the misalignment cannot be rescued by the usage of \vphantom.

Here's the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{1}{l_e^{1} l_e^{-1} l_e l_e^{\vphantom{3}-1}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Add empty superscripts where missing: `l_e^{}l_e^{-1}`. The `\vphantom` serves no purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately the main issue with the first two elements `l_e^{1} l_e^{-1}`. There's already a superscript present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minus sign has the same height and depth of the `+`, which *has* depth, so this pushes down the subscript a bit more than if only `1` is in it. For this reason, your `\vphantom{3}` does nothing.

Solution: use proper phantoms or smash the minus.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{1}{l_e^{\vphantom{-}1} l_e^{-1} l_e^{\vphantom{-}} l_e^{-1}}
\quad
  \frac{1}{l_e^{1} l_e^{\smash{-}1} l_e^{} l_e^{\smash{-}1}}
\quad
  \frac{1}{l_e^{1\mathstrut} l_e^{-1\mathstrut} l_e^{\mathstrut} l_e^{-1\mathstrut}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the `\mathstrut` device has its drawbacks.

Comment: Aligning subscripts when superscripts are involved is something of a black art. `;-)`

Comment: Thank you. The `\smash` version works nicely. However, I don't get your explanation completely. As you write `-` and `+` have finite _depth_. Shouldn't this push the subscript ever lower? I saw the opposite behaviour.

Comment: @somehow.different The rules for subscript and superscript placement are really complicated. Also the fact TeX uses cramped style in denominators has a role in this affair.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{1}{l_e^{\mathstrut{1}} l_e^{\mathstrut{-1}} l_e l_e^{\mathstrut{1}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I figured I'd add an alternative. As @egreg mentions in the comments, the rules for subscript and superscript placement are complicated. To bypass the "cramped" style in the denominator, you can add `\textstyle`, even though intuition tells us the denominator *should* already be in `\textstyle`. To even out the subscripts, add an empty exponent.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{1}{\textstyle l_e^{1} l_e^{-1} l^{}_e l_e^{-1}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```