# PGFplots: loglogaxis: Shrink the exponent's minus sign

Tags: pgfplots, scalebox

I do have a lot of loglogaxis plots in my document. Often the y-values pass through 1, i.e. from 0.5 to 2. Hence, the y-ticklabels are of the form 
[image: 10^1].

[image]

The minus sign adds a lot of extra space to the spacing of the y-label. I would like to stick with 10-base notation of the y tick labels. In this case,I do not want to use

```
log ticks with fixed point
```

I already found, [how to shrink the minus sign.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6071) How can I change specifically all the minus sign in the exponents of the tick labels in pgfplots?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\( \sqrt{\scalebox{0.5}[1.0]{\( - \)}\frac{1}{9}} \)

% cf.
\( \sqrt{-\frac{1}{9}} \) 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    xlabel={xlabel is nicely separated},
    ylabel={ylabel is displaced to far}
    ]
    \addplot
    table{
      x     y
      0.1   0.1
      1.0   1.0
      10.0  10.0
    };
  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for such a late answer but I recently had to do the same and came across this post so I thought I'd share what I did, in case anybody else needs it.

I assume there is a much more automatic way but since I am new to pgfplots it follows the completely manual way of defininy the tick positions and ticklabels explicitly. This is probly not something you want to do if you have many of such plots.

Here the result:

[image: Shortened minus still aligned properly]

The `ytick` and `yticklabels` are defined explicitly with the `\unaryminus` command defined earlier for convenience. Although optional, I find it convenient to let latex calculate the width of the longest label with `\settowidth` and then set that as the `text width` in the `yticklabel style` as well as set the alignment to right.

```
\documentclass{article}
% replaced minimal class with article, which is more appropriate for MWEs
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newcommand\unaryminus{\smash{\scalebox{0.5}[1.0]{\( - \)}}}
% \smash is used here to reduce the depth of the minus sign in the superscript, so the xlabels have the same height
\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylabelwidth}
\settowidth{\mylabelwidth}{$10^{\unaryminus 1}$}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    xlabel={xlabel is nicely separated},
    ylabel={ylabel is also nicely aligned},
    ytick={0.1, 1,10, 100},
    yticklabels={$10^{\unaryminus 1}$,$10^{0}$,$10^{1}$,$10^{2}$},
    yticklabel style={
      text width=\mylabelwidth,
      align=right, % alternatively use "left" 
    },
    xtick={0.1, 1,10, 100},
    xticklabels={$10^{\unaryminus 1}$,$10^{0}$,$10^{1}$,$10^{2}$},
    ]
    \addplot
    table{
      x     y
      0.1   0.1
      1.0   1.0
      10.0  10.0
      100.0  100.0
    };
  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: The `compat=newest` was added to stop pgfplots throwing a warning. It works without it. Also if somebody knows how to generate the labels and ticks automatically I'd be very much interested in that!

Comment: Thanks @Schweinebacke, I did not know that. Fixed it. Am I supposed to declare the edit explicitly in the answer itself or is it OK if I just edit it? I could not find a definitive style guide for that.

Comment: It's OK to just edit it. But it would also be good to explain, why you change something. See, e.g., Tørbjorns answer.

Comment: No need for apologies. Thank you for your answer. I solved this issues the same way, but didn't found the time to post here. I like your `\unaryminus` macro. I personally prefer the right aligned yticklabels.

Did you spotted the hanging first xticklabel? I solved this with the `\smash` command:
`\newcommand\unaryminus{\smash{\scalebox{0.5}[1.0]{\( - \)}}}`. Would you add this to your answer?

And still, having this automated, would be great!

Comment: For the vertical height and depth of superscripts see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297291/horizontally-misalligned-sub-superscripts-in-fractions-when-using-minus-sign). This led me to `\smash`.

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful comments. And no, I did not spot that but now it sticks out like a sore thumb. I would have never suspected a minus sign to have depth :). I added it to my answer and my thesis!

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `ylabel` closer to the axis, wouldn't that be a better method? With `compat=1.3` or higher, you can add `ylabel shift=-5pt` to move it `5pt` closer to the axis.

Unrelated note: [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% compat setting of 1.3 or higher required for ylabel shift to work
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    xlabel={xlabel is nicely separated},
    ylabel={ylabel is displaced to far},
    ylabel shift=-5pt
    ]
    \addplot
    table{
      x     y
      0.1   0.1
      1.0   1.0
      10.0  10.0
    };
  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Torbjørn,

This would have been the next step.